# How do I change the name in multiple files in the middle one time?

Tags: rename, powershell, autocmd

For example I have 190 files and I want to add `L001` in the middle. How can I do that using cmd command, or PowerShell if it is better? Also some numbers are 2 digits some are 1.

```
PP-SD01_S1_R1.fastq.gz
PP-SD05_S1_R2.fastq.gz

PP-SD09_S20_R1.fastq.gz
PP-SD025_S20_R2.fastq.gz

PP-SD039_S22_R1.fastq.gz
PP-SD039_S22_R2.fastq.gz
...
```

I want to add `L001` on each one of them between `S..` and `..R`. For example `PP-SD039_S22_L001_R1.fastq.gz`

Comment: if you refer to `cmd command` then it's probably off-topic here because cmd runs on Windows only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a regex to match the `S...` and the `R...` parts then insert `L001` between them

```
PS /tmp> Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.fastq.gz | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(S\d+)_(R\d+)', '$1_L001_$2' } -WhatIf
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: /tmp/PP-SD01_S1_R1.fastq.gz Destination: /tmp/PP-SD01_S1_L001_R1.fastq.gz".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: /tmp/PP-SD025_S20_R2.fastq.gz Destination: /tmp/PP-SD025_S20_L001_R2.fastq.gz".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: /tmp/PP-SD039_S22_R1.fastq.gz Destination: /tmp/PP-SD039_S22_L001_R1.fastq.gz".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: /tmp/PP-SD039_S22_R2.fastq.gz Destination: /tmp/PP-SD039_S22_L001_R2.fastq.gz".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: /tmp/PP-SD05_S1_R2.fastq.gz Destination: /tmp/PP-SD05_S1_L001_R2.fastq.gz".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: /tmp/PP-SD09_S20_R1.fastq.gz Destination: /tmp/PP-SD09_S20_L001_R1.fastq.gz".
PS /tmp>
```

Shorter version:

```
dir *.fastq.gz | ren -Ne { $_.Name -replace '(S\d+)_(R\d+)', '$1_L001_$2' } -wi
```

After verifying that the names are correct, remove `-WhatIf`/`-wi` to do the real renaming

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I will try using pearl as you suggest the code to me